# XML file SSIS to SQL Server = removing trailing 0s from decimal values in columns

Tags: sql-server, database, etl

I have few columns on my XML file with decimal values with no trailing 0s. But 0 are added when it is transferred into a SQL Server table. The table has 4 columns with decimal datatype (10,3). How do I remove the 0s after the decimal point from my columns?
I know the 0 doesn't change the value but it's just my boss doesn't want those 0 for some reason.

```
select 
    QUANTITY, cast (QUANTITY as float) as QUANTITY1 
from 
    dbo.XML_DATATYPE_TEST1
```

as it only displays for the time of query and that's it.

```
QUANTITY
```

My column should look like below

```
Quantity
-------
 1. 1.00
 2. 234.8900
 3. 56.09800

Quantity
-------
 1. 1
 2. 234.89
 3. 56.098
```

Help please.

Comment: Are they `float` or are they `decimal`? [Decimal types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql) are specified with a `precision` and `scale`, so there will always be `scale` places after the decimal point, even if they are 0s.

Comment: You didn't specify the data type of columns in the table, which is pretty critical here.

Comment: Why do you care about the trailing zeros? They don't change the value and your front end will display as many decimal places as you configure it to.

Comment: The table has 4 columns with decimal (10,3) datatype.  I know the 0 doesn't change the value but it's just my boss doesn't want those 0 for some reason.